# java how to make user friendly percentage output from float number

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
float fl = ((float)20701682/(float)20991474);
```

And that gives me `fl = 0.9861948`.

I would like to convert `0.9861948` to `2%` since `2%` has been downloaded.
I'm downloading a file and calculating progress.

Any help would be grate.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I guess you mean something like

```
int percentage = (1 - fl) * 100;
```

to calculate the percentage.

But for `fl = 0.9861948` this gives `1` (`1.38052` casted to int).

If you want `2` instead, you could use [`Math.ceil`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29):

```
int percentage = (int) Math.ceil((1 - fl) * 100); // gives 2
```

Comment: thanks that worked grate. Just a little tweek needed "double per =(1.0 - fl) * 100; int res = (int)per;"

Answer (score 29):

you have constant values in the code, you should replace them with the variables representing the amount downloaded and the total size:

```
    float downloaded = 50;
    float total = 200;
    float percent = (100 * downloaded) / total;
    System.out.println(String.format("%.0f%%",percent));
```

output:
    25%

Answer (score 6):

I wrote two methods below to convert a float number to a string displayed as percentage:

```
//without decimal digits 
public static String toPercentage(float n){
    return String.format("%.0f",n*100)+"%";
}

//accept a param to determine the numbers of decimal digits
public static String toPercentage(float n, int digits){
    return String.format("%."+digits+"f",n*100)+"%";
}
```

**Test Case1:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    float f = 1-0.9861948f;//your number,0.013805211
    System.out.println("f="+f);//f=0.013805211
    System.out.println(toPercentage(f));//1%
    System.out.println(toPercentage(f,2));//1.38%
}
```

**Test Case2:**

If you want 2% instead, try to input a param like this:

```
    float f = 1-0.9861948f;//your number,0.013805211
    f= (float)(Math.ceil(f*100)/100);//f=0.02
    System.out.println("f="+f);f=0.02
    System.out.println(toPercentage(f));//2%
    System.out.println(toPercentage(f,2));//2.00%
```

Comment: String.format("%.0f",n*100)+"%" is rather ugly. This is more compact:
String.format ( "%.0f%%", n * 100 );

Answer (score 2):

When you output the float just tell the string conversion to only allow no/one/whatever trailing digits:

`System.out.printf("We have downloaded: %.0f %%%n", (1-fl) * 100);`

But I'm not sure why exactly you'd want to round 1.4% to 2%.. if you really want that it gets a lot more complicated for really no good reason.

Comment: Good approach, but I doubt he wants to output the data to the console.

Comment: @JustinKSU Then replace `System.out.printf` with `String.format` - if he wants to show the number to the user he will have to format it as a string. For everything else the exact number is more useful

Answer (score 1):

How about (1.0 -fl ) * 100 ?

Convert this to an integer and you wouldn't have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Since percent means "per 100," perhaps you could multiple `fl` by 100. Since, for some reason, you want .98 to mean 2%, you would then subtract the result from 100.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
float allSize = ...;
float downloaded = ...;
int percent = (allSize - downloaded/100 * 100.0)/allSize 


(downloaded/100 * 100.0) - used for make two digit of fractional part;
```

Answer (score 0):

After applying the ((1-fl)*100) logic you can use [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) or [String.format()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
float fl = ((float)20701682 / (float)20991474)*100;
int pct = 100 - Math.floor(fl)
```